# why does the arraylist lenght become longer?

Tags: java

Firstly, English is not my primary language so I apologize for errors. Secondly I am also very new to Java.
I'm having a problem with an assigment which is supposed to generate a 'War' card game for two players with each 16 cards. I use a random number for the card values and two ArrayLists to store them. It works fine and correctly usually but sometimes it prints out this message:
 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 17, Size: 17`
From my understanding it means that the ArrayList got longer for some reason. Can someone explain why?
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class wargame{

     public static void main(String []args){
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList p1 = new ArrayList ();
    ArrayList p2 = new ArrayList ();
    int tri=0, empt1, empt2, point1=0,point2=0;
    String card1="", card2="";


    do {
      int x=rand.nextInt(8) + 7 ;
      p1.add(x);

    } while (p1.size()<=16);

    do {
      int x=rand.nextInt(8) + 7 ;
      p2.add(x);

    } while (p2.size()<=16);
    System.out.println("GAME!\n");
    System.out.println(p1+"\n"+p2+"\n");

    do {
        empt1=(int)p1.get(tri);
        if (empt1>10){
        switch (empt1)
        {
         case 11: card1="jack";
         break;
         case 12: card1="queen";
         break;
         case 13: card1="king";
         break;
         case 14: card1="ace";
         break;
         default: card1="error";
         break;
        } }
        empt2=(int)p2.get(tri);
        if (empt2>10){
        switch (empt2)
        {
         case 11: card2="jack";
         break;
         case 12: card2="queen";
         break;
         case 13: card2="king";
         break;
         case 14: card2="ace";
         break;
         default: card2="error";
         break;
        } 
    }
    if (empt1>10 && empt2>10)
    {    
     System.out.println("player one drew a "+card1+" and player two drew a "+card2);}
    else 
    { 
        if (empt1<=10 && empt2>10) 
    {
     System.out.println("player one drew a "+empt1+" and player two drew a "+card2);
    }
    else {
        if (empt1<=10 && empt2<=10)
        {
            System.out.println("player one drew a "+empt1+" and player two drew a "+empt2);

        }
    else {
        System.out.println("player one drew a "+card1+" and player two drew a "+empt2);

    }
    }
     }
     if (empt1<empt2)
     {
        point2++; 
     }
     if (empt1>empt2)
     {
        point1++; 
     }
     if (empt1==empt2)
     {
         if (tri>14)
         {
            System.out.println("\neven thougha battle would occur there are too litle cards to do so. nobody gets a point");
            break;
         }
     do {


     {  System.out.println("\n\nbattle");
        tri=tri+2;
        empt1=(int)p1.get(tri);
        empt2=(int)p2.get(tri);

        if (empt1<empt2)
     {
         System.out.println("\nplayer two won the battle");
        point2=point2+3; 
     }
     if (empt1>empt2)
     {
         System.out.println("\nplayer one won the battle");
        point1=point1+3; 
     }   
     }
     }
     while (empt1==empt2);

     }
     tri++;
     }
     while (tri!=16);

    if (point1<point2)
    {
       System.out.println("\nplayer TWO wins with "+point2+" points!"); 
    }
    else {System.out.println("\nplayer ONE wins with "+point1+" points!");}

     }

}
```

Comment: Index is 0 based and size is 1 based. AKA, for list of size one, the element is index 0, or `size()-1`

Comment: If you keep adding `while (p1.size()<=16)`, then the loop won't stop until size is 17. Your lists didn't "get longer". *You* created the lists with that size.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/ --- Seeing 5 end-braces (`}`) almost right after each other, at same indentation, without any open-braces between them, means that your code is very badly indented. Indent the code so the structure of the code matches the code blocks.

Comment: Why are you skipping tries with the `tri=tri+2` statement? And if all the remaining tries are different, why wouldn't that `do-while` run until you exceeded the list size? --- Anyway: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ (i.e. what line caused the error)

Answer (score 0):

Index starts with 0, so `getIndex(0)` would return the first value. Size starts with 1, so an arrayList of size 1 would return `1` for `getSize()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 17, Size: 17
```

This is saying that you are trying to access index array[17] , but because you only have an array size of 17, that index is out of bounds. So an array size of 17 will have a highest available index of array[16]

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is do while loop where you're doing `tri = tri +2`. You need to learn how to debug your code, IDEs are a great tool!

There are a few reasons why you're having this issue. The main issue is that you're adding 2 to `tri`. The other issue is that you're only picking a random number between 1 and then adding 7 to it. This only gives you 8 possibilities for numbers.

When I ran your code, `p1` was set to `{14, 10, 8, 11, 10, 9, 7, 14, 14, 8, 9, 9, 13, 11, 7, 12, 14}` and `p2` was set to `{12, 10, 12, 13, 9, 10, 10, 8, 14, 14, 7, 9, 9, 10, 7, 13, 14}`. As you can see, there are multiple instances where both arrays contain the same value in the same index. If `tri` was set to lets say 10, then the code would run through your do while loop until `tri` reaches 18 which throws the exception your seeing. `tri` should never have gone over 16.

I suggest you go through your code and break it down to small specific methods to make it a bit cleaner. Also you can replace your switch statements and the if statements with an arraylist containing all of your Card values which would cut down on your lines of code and make it less complex. You can call on the ArrayList by using `cardValue[empt1]` or something along those lines.